# An issue about AS3 Socket connecting to C++ WinSocket

Tags: c++, actionscript-3, sockets

there:
    I wrote an AS3 Client Socket in an AIR Project and the other is a C++ Server.
    In the C++ Server, I use non-blocking socket type with networking APIs ioctlsocket() and recv().
    Every time the AS3 client socket connecting to the C++ Server, it shows the connection is success,
    but I got the return vaulue of recv() which is 0 in the next tick right after the successful connection from AS3 client.
    According to MSDN, when recv() returns 0, it means the client socket closed gracefully.
    But when I test the connection with C++ client socket, it won't happen.
    The Client and Server are all at local, so the client is connecting to "127.0.0.1", and the port is 5001.

Comment: Have you implemented a crossdomain policy file?

Comment: Well then this is the issue. Read about cross domain policy file and how flash uses it with sockets. There's specific request that needs specific response, otherwise Flash closes the connection. Check it out and if it works out well - you can write the answer and close the question :)

Comment: could I load a local policy file?
Ex:
Security.loadPolicyFile("Y:\crossdomain.xml");

Comment: No, loading it this way means that you will use it for HTTP connection. If you use sockets, the socket server must provide such a file when the client requests it (done automatically as first request).

Comment: OK, so what you mean is that : although the client socket is connecting to localhost , it still need a crossdomain.xml in server application, is this right?

Comment: Check this one: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e08.html  It describes it well. About the localhost - I 99% sure you pretty much always need that crappy file. The problem is that it's not easy to understand what's going on behind the scene..

Comment: One more question : Will AIR applications send <policy-file-request/> to server automatically？Because I found my c++ server did not get the request from client both on port 843 and my app port. Very appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found that AIR Applications do not need crossdomain.xml, I think it may be my function writing style made the AIR socket's auto disconnect condition. Because I create a socket in another function and then preserve it in a * type object, which might made it be garbage-collection.